# Event binding on dynamically created elements from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In my application, added code to append div elements dynamically to its parent div element. I can able to access predefined iframe div elements by using `$('#FrameId').contents().find('#id');`. But when i try to get newly appended div element, then it shows **undefined**. Why I can't able to access newly added div elements?

For appending new div element, used below code:

```
$('#frameId').contents().find("#id").append("<div class="sample">Some text</div>");
```

When I try to get newly added div element, used below code:

```
$('#frameId').contents().find(".sample").click(function(){});
```

in which, click event is not triggered, because it can't able to find .sample div element.

Comment: push those code into inside the load function $('#frameId').load(function(){    $(this).contents().find("#id").append("<div class="sample">Some text</div>");   $(this).contents().find(".sample").click(function(){}); });

Comment: Have you checked that new element is appended to the DOM?

Comment: [Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector,  **now or in the future** , based on a specific set of root elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iframe [load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event please find below sample for more info.

And for click event on dynamically created element you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using [on().](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

```
$('#frameId').on('load', function(){
    $(this).contents().find('body').on('click', '.sample', function(e){
       //Do some stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this code, but it's not working. I think newly added elements are not attached to DOM element. When I tried to get newly added element, i can't able to get it. But I tried with same html code added predefined in iframe, i can able to get it. Any idea? - @Curiousdev